# Problem plotting convex hull of random points

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, convex-hull

Something that escapes me...

When I run the first program below in a Jupyter notebook:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import random
from scipy.spatial import ConvexHull
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

points = np.random.rand(30, 2)

hull = ConvexHull(points)

plt.plot(points[:,0], points[:,1], 'o')

for simplex in hull.simplices:
    plt.plot(points[simplex,0], points[simplex,1], 'k-')
```

I get, as expected, a plot of points and convex hull:

[image]

And when, after that, I run the second program below:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import random
from scipy.spatial import ConvexHull, convex_hull_plot_2d

points = np.random.rand(30, 2)

hull = ConvexHull(points)

convex_hull_plot_2d(hull)
```

I get a double plot !

[image]

**What am I missing?**

Comment: Can you elaborate? Are there two axes in the same figure? Does the same plot get plotted in two figures? Running your programs individually only makes one plot. Did you run the first, then the second? Because if you did, then _of course_ it'll make two plots -- one from the first code, one from the second.

Comment: Yes, I ran the first, then the second. It comes from that? But how possible? I recreate new points and a new hull...

Comment: I didn't realize you ran the entire second code. Are you sure that's the entire second code? I ran it, and I get a single plot https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbWlb.png

Comment: It's really happening. I opened a Jupyter notebook and wrote these 2 pieces of codes in 2 different cells. Running the first cell gives one plot (with some random points). Afterwords, running the second cell gives me 2 same plots (with - of course - some other random points).

Comment: Ah, I think this is something to do with Jupyter notebooks then. It shows two plots _even when_ the second code is run by itself (and the first code isn't in the notebook at all). _Really weird!_ https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/ipython/ipython-in-depth/7e5ce96cc9251083979efdfc393425f1229a4a68?filepath=binder%2Fcode2.ipynb

Comment: Always add `plt.show()` when you ready to plot.

Comment: @swatchai, it works well, now. I hadn't paid attention to the importance of `plt.show()`...Thanks for reminding me of that!